# What is the correct order to close input streams?

Tags: java

I am studying a Java code example about reading file using input stream. I observed that there are 3 input streams initialized in the order of `fis`, `bis`, and `dis`(typed `FileInputStream`, `BufferedInputStream`, and `DataInputStream` correspondingly), with dependency fis<--(depends-on)--bis<--(depends-on)--dis. I also observed that they are closed in the same order: `fis`, `bis`, then `dis`.

My question is: **shouldn't them be closed in REVERSE order?** i.e. the latestly initialized shall be closed first?

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedinputstream-example/) is the code example. I also pasted it here:

```
    public class BufferedInputStreamExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:\\testing.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            while (dis.available() != 0) {
                System.out.println(dis.readLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
                bis.close();
                dis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: afaik closing one of them will close the other..

Comment: Generally you only need to close the outermost stream.

Comment: He may be referring to this [MKYong tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedinputstream-example/).  @shmosel Yes this is also my recollection.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's linked in the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal thing to do is to only close the outermost stream. `DataInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` are both types of `FilterInputStream`, [whose `close` method specifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#close--) that it calls the close method of the underlying stream. So you do not need to explicitly close the others or even maintain a reference to them in a variable. For example it is fine to initialize `dis` as:

```
dis = new DataInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(file)));
```

In practice, assuming the classes are implemented properly according to the spec, it does not matter whether you close any 1, any 2, or all 3 of the streams, in any order, or any number of times, because:

1. As said, closing an outer stream closes the inner stream.
2. Closing an already closed stream harmlessly does nothing. (`InputStream` and `OutputStream` implement the `Closeable` interface, [whose `close` method states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close--) "If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.")
3. Only the `FileInputStream` actually *needs* to be closed, since it is the only one which holds open a real filesystem resource and therefore is the only stream which has visible side effects if held open (e.g., you cannot delete the file). The `BufferedInputStream` and `DataInputStream` are ordinary objects, which can be garbage collected in the ordinary way, whether closed or not. The `FileInputStream` will also be closed when garbage collected if you forgot to do it, but it's prudent to do it as soon as possible, since there are no guarantees about *when* garbage collection occurs.

So the example you posted is over-engineered, but not dangerous.

In modern Java (7+) the far more elegant way to ensure the closure of everything in your example, rather than using a `finally` block, is to use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, which lets you declare the streams, open them, and guarantee their closure, in one go:

```
try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(file)))) {
    while (dis.available() != 0) {
        System.out.println(dis.readLine());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you only need to close the outer object (DataInputStream). it will close all the objects it depends on.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest in the reverse of the order they are opened (so `dis`, `bis` then `fis`), but such isn't required (just style) or better yet - [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
File file = new File("C:\\testing.txt");
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis)) {
    while (dis.available() != 0) {
        System.out.println(dis.readLine());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and not worry about the order of closing

```
    public class BufferedInputStreamExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:\\testing.txt");

        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis)) {

            while (dis.available() != 0) {
                System.out.println(dis.readLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the docs are not 100% clear, it looks like closing the `DataInputStream` should be sufficient.

Both `DataInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` are subclasses of `FilterInputStream`, and here is its documentation of `close()` (Java 7 SE):

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream. This method simply performs **in**.close().

Here `in` is the wrapped stream.

Assuming neither class overrides the behaviour of the superclass, closing the `DataInputStream` will recursively close all the wrapped streams.